# Application not yet validated by Google

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I'm facing an issue with new user authentication.

> “Application not yet validated by Google.”

I received few weeks ago an email about new policy.

According to email, we are in internal case so no more action is required.

Did I miss something?

[image: oauth]

Comment: @Naina this is a set up issue what code would you like to see besides the fact that they have set the project internal?

Comment: Referring to share the relevant information and readable post; in order to improve new user's Post Creation Practices.

Comment: @Naina the question includes all relevant information needed to understand the issue.   This is not a coding problem.

Comment: Not addressing coding problem here.

Answer (score 2):

An unverified app is a web application or Apps Script that requests a sensitive OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive applications.

You need to go through verification before you launch a user-facing app. You can continue to build and test your application while waiting to complete verification. When your app is successfully verified, the unverified app screen will be removed from your client.

- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)
- [OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)

**internal**

Internal apps: if your app is an internal web app for users in the same G Suite domain and the app is associated with a Cloud Organization that all of your users belong to, you don't need to go through verification. Learn more about [public and internal applications](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#public-and-internal).

If your new user is seeing this i would suggest you check that they are logging in with their g suite account only those accounts are going to be able to get though the verification requirement.

Comment: Hello DalmTo, Thanks for the note. User trying to connect to the App are using domain account only. Is there a way to know what is the reason they are facing this page?

Comment: Not that i am aware of if you are seeing the page then you need to go though verification.   Once you do i suspect that you will hear from google and they will note that you have set it internal and you will be all set.  I have seen a few issues with internal detection lately.   I am going to contact google to see if i can get any clarification